# Split function usage in Perl

Tags: perl, function, if-statement, split

I was using split function to split the $line by '|' and I want to check the protein name which is `$val[2]` after splitting! when I print its giving correct element but when I use it in if statement, even the given condition is false it's giving yes.

Please tell me what's the mistake

```
#!/usr/bin/perl


$line = ">sp|P01011|AACT_HUMAN| Alpha-1:-antichymotrypsin: OS=Homo sapiens GN=SERPINA3 PE=1 SV=2";

my @val = split(/\|/, $line);

print " $val[2]\n";

if($val[2] == 'gh')
{
   print " \n yes\n";    
}    
else    
{    
   print "no";    
}
```

Comment: All string comparisons are done with operators whose names consist of two letters:  eq, ne, lt, le, ge, and gt.  For comparing numbers, you use ==, !=, >=, <=, etc., which are operator names composed of two symbols.  *Strings have operators that are spelled with letters...Strings have operators that are spelled with letters*.

Answer (score 3):

`==` is used to compare numbers. To compare strings, use `eq`:

```
if ($val[2] eq 'gh')
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

if($val[2] == 'gh')

use

if($val[2] eq 'gh')